# Ionic 5 Native HTTP: Type HTTP does not have 'emod' property

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

I created a new Ionic Capacitor app with the tabs template and only added like 5 lines of code just to test the native HTTP package of Ionic. Now the app just won't start. It gives me following error

`Uncaught Error: Type HTTP does not have 'ɵmod' property.    at getNgModuleDef (core.js:1127)    at recurse (core.js:25209)    at recurse (core.js:25220)    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:25205)    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:25319)    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:28937)    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:29183)    at Module.zUnb (main.ts:11)    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)    at Object.0 (main.js:11)`

Comment: Hello, could you please share your code ?